Open firefox with xinit to a specified url
How do i open firefox to a specific url without using the kiosk mode?
So i have a minimal arch installation with only xorg  running.
And this is what my script currently looks like
#!/bin/bash
sudo xinit firefox $* -- :1
xdotool search --name ".*Mozilla Firefox" windowsize 2560 1440
export DISPLAY=:1
sleep 10
xdotool search --name ".*Mozilla Firefox" windowfocus key F11

Problem with this is that i dont have a way to open a specific url, so to open the page i currently wanted, i had to make it my default home page in firefox. I know i can use the
firefox --kiosk --private window [url] mode, but id like to get this working
And i also think my xdotools are broken, they worked in the beginning but have stopped since

xinit doesn't exit until client process exit. Also if firefox process creates window faster than in 10 seconds, you are wasting the rest of time.
You can workaround this by running firefox in background and force xdotool to wait for window became visible. It's convenient to place firefox and xdotool into a shell script:
#!/bin/sh

firefox "$@" &

xdotool \
    search --sync --onlyvisible --class firefox \
    windowsize 2560 1440 \
    windowfocus --sync key F11

wait %%

And run it:
$ xinit ./start_browser https://google.com -- :1

Note from man 1 xinit:

Both  the  client  program name and the server program name must begin with a slash (/) or a period (.).  Otherwise, they are treated as an arguments to be appended to their respective startup lines.

Note, xinit will initialize DISPLAY variable in client environment, you don't need to specify it.
Note, usually you don't need to run xinit with sudo.
Of course, you can run everything in a single command line:
$ xinit /bin/sh -c "firefox http://google.com & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class firefox windowsize 2560 1440 windowfocus --sync key F11; wait %%" -- :1

